# Custom enum underlying type

Tags: c++, enums

Can I define a type to use as the underlying type of an enumeration? Something like this:

```
struct S {
    S(int i) : value(i) {}
    operator int() { return value; }

    int value;
};

enum E : S {
    A, B, C
};
```

The error message tells me that S must be an integral type. I have tried to specialize `std::is_integral` like the following, but it seems that in this context, "integral type" really means one of the fundamental types.

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct is_integral<S> : public true_type {};
}
```

So, using any version of C++, is there a way to make a custom type pass off as an integral type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I define a type to use as the underlying type of an enumeration?

You can only use integral types to define `enum`s, not any old type.

For example, you can use

```
enum E : char {
    A, B, C
};
```

to indicate the value of `E` will be of type `char`. But you can't use

```
enum E : S {
    A, B, C
};
```

From the [C++11 Standard, 3.9.1/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.fundamental#7):

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type.

Comment: So the "integral type" in this context has nothing to do with `std::is_integral`?

Comment: The example you posted will be a subversion of the intent of `std::is_integral`. I am not sure whether there is anything in the language to prevent that.

Comment: [Looks like specializing anything in `<type_traits>` is undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace). I should have looked more thoroughly. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345486/why-specializing-a-type-trait-could-result-in-undefined-behaviour) (thanks HolyBlackCat).

Answer (score 2):

> **std::is_integral** 
>   checks whether T is an integral type. Provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is the type `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, or any implementation-defined extended integer types, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants. Otherwise, value is equal to false.

This is an excerpt from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).
This means that an `enum` must be using one of the following types:

`bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`.

Comment: [That doesn't mean you can't specialize `is_integral`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9828b8eaf4d59e3)

Comment: I don't believe I wrote anything contrary.

Comment: @Nelxiost You have it backwards. `std::is_integral` indicates if a type is integral, which is defined by the standard and the implementation. Specializing things in `std::` is (usually) UB

Comment: @Shiro Your answer lets me think that an `enum` must be using a type T for which `std::is_integral<T>() == true`. Which is not the case.

Comment: @Nelxiost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345486/why-specializing-a-type-trait-could-result-in-undefined-behaviour